# do django version 2.2 and above support get_by_id method for model managers

Tags: django, django-models

class ProductManager(models.Manager):
def get_queryset(self):
return ProductQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

```
def get_by_id(self):
    qs = self.get_queryset().filter(id=id)
    if qs.count() == 1:
        return qs.first()
    return None
```

Comment: Please edit your question and:
a) use block of code functionality (triple ``` at beginning and at end) to encompass your code. Example:
``` (new line)
code (new line)
```
b) add some description of this block of code.

Answer (score 1):

Te `get_by_id` method is defined in *your* `ProductManager`, hence the Django version does not matter. Furthermore the logic of the function is valid, but not very efficient, since it makes two queries.

You can implement this more effectively with:

```
from django.core.exceptions ObjectDoesNotExist, MultipleObjectsReturned

class ProductManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return ProductQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)
    
    def get_by_id(self):
        try:
            return self.get_queryset().get(id=id)
        except (ObjectDoesNotExist, MultipleObjectsReturned):
            return None
```

Comment: my error is : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_queryset'

Comment: please help me why i am getting this

Comment: @user13336549: how did you use the manager in the `Product` model?

Answer (score 0):

NO, django version 1.7 and below will support this methods get_by_id.

versions after 1.7 will not work this.